# asp.net menu control staticBottomSeparatorImage appears underneath horizontal menu

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm using the ASP menu control, .NET 4.0. I finally got the styles working thanks to the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655377/how-to-style-an-asp-net-menu-with-css) but now that I've set the controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion in my web.config to "4.0" I'm seeing my separator image underneath the Menu control.

```
<div class="menuContainer">
        <asp:Menu ID="_menu" runat="server" EnableTheming="true" DataSourceID="_siteMap" CssClass="menuClass" IncludeStyleBlock="false" 
            Orientation="Horizontal" StaticBottomSeparatorImageUrl="../images/menuSepImage.jpg" OnMenuItemDataBound="_menu_OnDataBound">
        </asp:Menu>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="_siteMap" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
    </div>
```

I tried pulling out the default CSS styles that are auto-generated, and setting IncludeStyleBlock="false" but setting the #_menu img.horizontal-separator {} class in my CSS doesn't do anything, which is why I'm trying to set it with the StaticBottomSeparatorImageUrl property.

Comment: I just figured this out. in case anyone else has this problem, I added a class for .horizontal-separator {position:relative; top: -36px;} and set the height of my containing div menuContainer.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comment. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> This solved the issue in case anyone else is wondering Add to CSS: `.horizontal-separator { position:relative; top:-36px; }` And set the height of the div that contains the menu.