# asp:Menu not applying style to submenu items

Tags: asp.net, css

For some reason the "StaticMenuItemStyle" is not being applied to the submenus. Any ideas?

```
            <asp:Menu ID="rightMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="6px" BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="White" VerticalPadding="4px" ItemSpacing="3px"  BackColor="#a8e2ff"  ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" />
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Reports" Value="Reports">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Price List" Value="Price List"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Sales Managers Tool" Value="Sales Managers Tool">
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Sales Rep Tool" Value="Sales Rep Tool"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Product Dev Recap" Value="Product Dev Recap"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Master Cost Summary" Value="Master Cost Summary">
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Enabled="False" Text="Integrity Report" Value="Integrity Report">
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Enabled="False" Text="JDE UPC/SCC Report" 
                        Value="JDE UPC/SCC Report"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Enabled="False" Text="Items Not Matching JDE Criteria" 
                        Value="Items Not Matching JDE Criteria"></asp:MenuItem>
                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Admin" Value="Admin" Enabled="false"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StaticSelectedStyle property of menu control can be used to control the appearance of the menu item selected by the user in a static menu.

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.staticselectedstyle.aspx

Follow this question for reference:

[How to style an asp.net menu with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655377)

it is the asp.net forum question and hope you will solve your problem after reading this one..
may be it will guide you..

[Help applying styles to menu items](http://forums.asp.net/t/1097697.aspx/1)

Comment: Switched to LevelMenuItemStyles. Thanks.