# Where can I find a tutorial about changing the appearance of the ASP.NET Menu Control?

Tags: asp.net, menu

I am trying to learn how to use the ASP.NET Menu control.  The MSDN information which I find [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is sketchy and not sufficiently informative.  I am particularly interested in how to change the appearance of the control.  The menu as it appears in the sample ASP.NET Web Application is usable, but not beautiful.  For instance, one thing that I would like to accomplish is to make the tab which corresponds to the currently displayed page have the same background color as the page being displayed, so as to make it clear that it represents the currently displayed page.  I have been unable to figure out how to do this, nor do the docs I have found say anything about it.  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some good links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478963.aspx

[How to style an asp.net menu with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655377/how-to-style-an-asp-net-menu-with-css)

http://peterkellner.net/2008/05/19/codecampwebsiteseries2/

Comment: Your first link actually deals with an open-source menu control -- not exactly what I was asking, but what the heck it might be valuable anyway.  The second is fascinating and causes me to rethink whether I want to use the MS-supplied control at all.  The third causes me to rethink my rethought.  At home I have DevExpress, which has a very nice tab control, but at work I only have the choice between the Infragistics WebTab (which is another feature-ridden item I am finding hard to fathom) or the MS-supplied Menu, which I hoped (forlornly it turns out) would provide a simple and quick solution.

Answer (score -1):

After a search at my local Barnes and Noble bookstore, the best resource I could find for the Menu control was a book written principally by Stephen Walther, *ASP.NET 4 Unleashed*.  It has about 28 pages of material on the control, including some material on how to change its appearance, starting at page 1020 -- it's a BIG book, obviously.  I actually bought the book ($60 -- Yikes! -- although with a B&N membership it was a bit less).

I guess I will see if there are any other answers to this question that pop up, before I Accept an answer.

Comment: To the downvoter: What, you don't like Stephen Walther or something?