# Customize design for nagivationmenu

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net

i work on project asp.net and vb .net , i want asking how i want to create a beautiful and smart look of my navigation menu bar in asp.net because currently i just use default navigation menu . it look like normal . i want to design like beautiful and look professional. any one can suggest and also can share the tips or instruction for i learn and do it by myself.

```
enter code here`  <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                     <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="List Request"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Request.aspx" Text="Request Section"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/defevo2.aspx" Text="Evalution Section"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Decision.aspx" Text="Decision Section"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/closeup.aspx" Text="User Close Up Section"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>`
```

but his look like simple design. i want more attractive look. here my nagivation pictures
[image: mydefault nagivationmenu]

i want it look more beautiful and smart for navigation menu

Comment: i just want get advice and asking some question why some of people dont like to share but more LOVE to vote not useful.. dam so hurt.duh duh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather keep the ASP:Menu.  It is the most future proof option.  If you want to make it look good, look at some CSS styling examples on the net, or you may even find some AJAX menu extensions if you hunt.

See: 
http://monirblog.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/styling-asp-net-menu-control-with-css-example/
[How to style an asp.net menu with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655377/how-to-style-an-asp-net-menu-with-css)

for some further tips

Also look at http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/advanced-css-menu for some UL styling tips that can be adapted to work with a server menu.

Comment: ow really @anthony horne. i will follow your advice but i will also do look at your link thanks for advice me

Comment: look at below some people just copy your answer to get point not fair and not so professioanal

Comment: @kolopopo Not to worry, as long as you're on the right track, then I am happy.

Comment: ok thanks for help.. i just through your link.. this mean alot to me.. im happy too ;)